# Spark Dataframe select based on column index

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

How do I select all the columns of a dataframe that has certain indexes in Scala?

For example if a dataframe has 100 columns and i want to extract only columns (10,12,13,14,15), how to do the same?

Below selects all columns from dataframe `df` which has the column name mentioned in the Array colNames:

```
df = df.select(colNames.head,colNames.tail: _*)
```

If there is similar, colNos array which has

```
colNos = Array(10,20,25,45)
```

How do I transform the above `df.select` to fetch only those columns at the specific indexes.

Answer (score 10):

You can `map` over `columns`:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col

df.select(colNos map df.columns map col: _*)
```

or:

```scala
df.select(colNos map (df.columns andThen col): _*)
```

or:

```scala
df.select(colNos map (col _ compose df.columns): _*)
```

All the methods shown above are equivalent and don't impose performance penalty. Following mapping:

```
colNos map df.columns
```

is just a local `Array` access ([constant time access for each index](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html)) and choosing between `String` or `Column` based variant of `select` doesn't affect the execution plan:

```
val df = Seq((1, 2, 3 ,4, 5, 6)).toDF

val colNos = Seq(0, 3, 5)

df.select(colNos map df.columns map col: _*).explain
```

```
== Physical Plan ==
LocalTableScan [_1#46, _4#49, _6#51]
```

```scala
df.select("_1", "_4", "_6").explain
```

```
== Physical Plan ==
LocalTableScan [_1#46, _4#49, _6#51]
```

Answer (score 4):

@user6910411's answer above works like a charm and the number of tasks/logical plan is similar to my approach below. **BUT** my approach is a bit faster. 
 
So,
I would suggest you to go with the `column names` rather than `column numbers`. `Column names` are **much safer** and **much ligher** than using `numbers`. You can use the following solution :

```
val colNames = Seq("col1", "col2" ...... "col99", "col100")

val selectColNames = Seq("col1", "col3", .... selected column names ... )

val selectCols = selectColNames.map(name => df.col(name))

df = df.select(selectCols:_*)
```

If you are hesitant to write all the 100 column names then there is a shortcut method too

```
val colNames = df.schema.fieldNames
```

Answer (score 2):

**Example: Grab first 14 columns of Spark Dataframe by Index using Scala.**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col

// Gives array of names by index (first 14 cols for example)
val sliceCols = df.columns.slice(0, 14)
// Maps names & selects columns in dataframe
val subset_df = df.select(sliceCols.map(name=>col(name)):_*)
```

You **cannot** simply do this (as I tried and failed):

```
// Gives array of names by index (first 14 cols for example)
val sliceCols = df.columns.slice(0, 14)
// Maps names & selects columns in dataframe
val subset_df = df.select(sliceCols)
```

The reason is that you have to convert your datatype of Array[String] to Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Column] in order for the slicing to work.

**OR** Wrap it in a function using Currying (high five to my colleague for this):

```
// Subsets Dataframe to using beg_val & end_val index.
def subset_frame(beg_val:Int=0, end_val:Int)(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
  val sliceCols = df.columns.slice(beg_val, end_val)
  return df.select(sliceCols.map(name => col(name)):_*)
}

// Get first 25 columns as subsetted dataframe
val subset_df:DataFrame = df_.transform(subset_frame(0, 25))
```